# How to set Auto-Layout-Constraints for ImageView in ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uikit

I want to display a zoomable image in a ScrollView. Also, the ViewController should contain a toolbar.

I have set the following constraints:

- Toolbar: Left: 0, Right: 0, Bottom Layout Guide: 0
- ScrollView: Top Layout Guide: 0, Left: 0, Right: 0, Toolbar: 0
- ImageView: each 0 to ScrollView, centered vertically and horizontally

However, the image View ist never at the top... Do you know why and how to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
topAnchor
```

instead of:

```
toplayoutGuide
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the image to the top.  Go into storyboard click on Adjust Scroll View Insets(remove checkmark) on the View Controller.

EDIT:Image Attached

[image: IBImage]
Or in code on the view controller.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

This should get your image to the top of the scrollview.

Comment: If your image is still not filling the screen comment back and I will show you the best setup to achieve what you want but based on the screenshot you have it all except what I put above.